# Jquery replacewith - reading the id value

Tags: jquery, replacewith

Using this code, if I change the dropdown list containing opt1/opt2 I get an alert showing the ID as 'drop'

If I clicking in the 'clickme' test entry box, this changes to a new dropdown, but when I change an option in that, there is no alert issued to tell me the ID.

```
<script language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#test').bind('click', function() {
            $(this).replaceWith('<select id="test" name="test"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option value="audi">Audi</option></select>');
        });

        $("select").change(function(event) {
            alert(this.id);
        });
    });
</script>

<form>
    <input id='test' name='test' type='text' value='ClickMe.'><br>
    <select id='drop' name='drop'>
        <option value='0'></option>
        <option value='1'>Opt1</option>
        <option value='2'>Opt2</option>
    </select><br>

    <input type='submit' value='submit'><br>

    <?php
        if (isset($_REQUEST['test'])) echo $_REQUEST['test'];
    ?>
```

Why can't I see the `id` of the new dropdown list ?

Thanks

Comment: ***"As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements. "*** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

event delegation

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#test').bind('click', function () {
        $(this).replaceWith('<select id="test" name="test"><option value="volvo">Volvo</option><option value="saab">Saab</option><option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option><option value="audi">Audi</option></select>');
    });

    $('form').on('change', 'select[name="test"]', function (event) {
        alert(this.id);
    });

});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/PYjBY/)

When you use a normal event registration model, it will register the handlers directly to the targeted which are present in the dom at the point of the handler registration execution. So elements which are added later dynamically will not get those handlers.

The solution to this is to use event delegation, in this model the handler is registered to a ancestor element which will be present when the page is loaded with the a selector to filter out the source element. This makes use of event propagation - events happening in an element is propagated to all the ancestor elements(there are few exceptions like focus event). So an event happening in an element gets propagated to the ancestor element in one of them the handler is registered then the events source element(event.target) and its ancestors is matched against the selector passed as the second parameter, if it is satisfied then the handler is executed.

Comment: ...which fixes the problem because...?

Comment: I agree with @nnnnnn this does indeed fix the problem, but you should educate the OP as to why your answer helps. Teach a man to fish.. etc.

Comment: Quick thought, can this only affect the newly created dropdown and not opt1/opt2 ?  Thanks :)

Comment: @user1932360 yes you can target it by adding the `name` selector

Comment: Sorry can you explain that ?? Thx

Comment: why use .bind if you can use .on there too?

Answer (score 0):

When elements are inserted dynamically into the DOM (Document Object Model), for example using Ajax, then all event handlers have to be attached to parent elements. So for new items you need to apply [.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to a parent element

```
$('form').on('change', "select", function(event) {
  alert(this.id);// by javascript
  // or
  alert($(this).attr("id");// by jquery
});
```

Comment: _"all event handlers have to be attached to parent elements"_ - Well, that's one way to deal with dynamically added elements, probably the best way in most cases, but you don't have to do it that way - you can also attach event handlers directly to the elements in question after they're added.

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
$(document).on('change', 'select', function(event) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

If you are using jQuery1.6 or under, use .live

```
$("select").live('change', function(event) {
    alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: Yes, Thank you now the live function has been removed in jQuery1.9 and is replaced with on function of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

when this code is invoked:

$(this).replaceWith('VolvoSaabMercedesAudi');

it unbinds the select change event that is binded on document ready